# Handling Duplicate Database Entries with C# and the Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, duplicates, object-model

Let's say that I have an object model with many different objects that I then, using the Entity Framework map to database tables. That all works fine. The problem is what happens when I want to save more objects to the database. The objects in the model are interconnected, so when I am saving objects to the database, they may have references to objects that are already in the database.

For example, if I have an object called `Person` which has a property `Friends` which in itself is a list of people. This means that there is a table of Persons in the database and each of these has a list of friends which are identified by their ID's. Assuming that if the ID's of two people are the same then they are the same person, then I believe the Entity Framework will throw an error if I try to add them again. So the problem is when I add another person object who already has a list of friends, then I want to add friends who are not in the database, and I do not want to add the ones that already are in the database. Also each of those people may have friends who are/aren't in the database and I want them considered too. Another thing to consider is that even if the person is already in the database I want to look through their list of friends and add any new ones.

I feel like this should be a fairly common problem when working with databases, but I'm probably using the wrong vocabulary since nothing useful is actually coming up in all of my searches. It mostly deals with how to scan databases for duplicates after the fact or something like that. I want this to be handled in a business logic C# code layer through an Entity-Framework-approved venue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you pose is valid, but it does not fundamentally differ from adding objects to a `Dictionary` or a `HashSet`. You simply have to check whether a certain `Person` or related `Friend` is already contained in the `Dictionary` or if you will the Databasetable. The beauty of using the Entity Framework is that it makes these operations very similar.

So, you can use either a method like `context.People.Contains(newPerson)` (you must implement `IEquatable<Person> for that), or`context.People.Find(id).

Likewise you can use

```
   foreach(friend in newPerson.Friends)
   {
    if(!context.People.Contains(friend)
      context.People.Add(friend)
  }
```

Comment: SO won't let me edit this....you if statement should be if ( !context.People.Contains(friend))